# Replicating object function across various model files in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, model, modularity

I am looking to replicate a given object function across various model files

As you can see below, the 2 things I need to vary across the model are

1)  the "guser" string
 2)  the self.xxx

SIMPLIFIED CODE SAMPLE:

```
  def self.get_all
       statement="SELECT * FROM gusers WHERE"
       results = results + self.find_by_sql(["#{statement} #{statements[shard_id]}"])
       return results
  end
```

It would be great if you can provide code to help out here - thanks!

Comment: what is `statements[shard_id]`, where does `results` come from and and why do you need to change the `self.xxx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a module like this (suggesting gusers is the table to the current model)

```
module SharedFunctions
  def self.get_all
    statement = "SELECT * FROM #{self.table_name} WHERE"
    #... I don't understand what you wanne do here
  end
end
```

And than in you models:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SharedFunctions
end
```

**UPDATE**:

But what I really would do would look like this:

```
module SharedFunctions
  def self.get_all
    self.all :conditions => ...
  end
end
```

More information about Conditions can be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Or even better you can use scopes:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :get_all, :conditions => ...
end
```

Comment: so i would define table_name in each model?

Comment: no, it's already there sponsored by the rails developers (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002286)

Comment: thanks a lot! named_scope looks awesome but we are sharding our DB (hence losing a large part of the rails coolness), so the module idea looks like it will work the best